# Testing APNS on firebase test lab

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-test-lab

I am working on an iOS application that rely heavily on push notifications. We are planning to use Firebase Teslab to test it.
We have managed to get some simple test running on the firebase devices.

But we are encountering a blocker as the devices on firebase  are not able to register/receive push notifications. Everything works fine when we are testing locally. The issue is probably that device on firebase don't have the required certificates or provisioning profiles.

I was wondering if anyone has managed to test application with APNS on firebase test lab.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already concluded the issue is due to certificates and the provisioning profiles. Test Lab resigns the app to be able to run it in their infrastracture. Unfortunately this means that only a small set of entitlements is supported. I'm not that familiar how APN works, but I assume there is also an authentication step that happens with the server and since the provisioning profile is replaced it won't authenticate your app correctly.